# Alternative derivations of vis-viva equation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, orbital-motion

The [proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vis-viva_equation) of the vis-viva equation of orbital  mechanics found on wikipedia looks, in my opinion, somewhat convoluted and unenlightening. Considering the simplicity and importance of the vis-viva equation, is there a shorter or more insightful derivation?

The vis-viva equation states that for a Kepler orbit of a mass around a central mass $M$, the magnitude of the velocity at any distance $r$ from the center obeys $v^2 = GM(\frac{2}{r}-\frac{1}{a})$, where $a$ is the semi-major axis of the orbit.
It is equivalent to saying that the energy of a Kepler orbit with semi-major axis $a$ is $-\frac{GM}{2a}$.
This is a very natural generalization of the 'circular' case where the total energy is $-\frac{GM}{2r}$.

Because of the simplicity of the result, I guessed that there could be a relatively straightforward derivation. The derivation on wikipedia involves quite some algebra and, importantly, only holds for elliptical orbits.

---

$$v^2 = GM\left(\frac{2}{r} - \frac{1}{a} \right)$$

Comment: I suggest you should add some more detail, namely the equation itself, and which bit of the derivation you find "unenlightening".
As it stands, this question is not posed very well.

Comment: The derivation given at Wikipedia only applies when one of the masses is negligibly small. For the general 2-body problem the energy is $ -\frac{GMm}{2a} $, and the specific energy is $ -\frac{G(M+m)}{2a} $.

Comment: I have a simpler derivation of the vis-viva equation, assuming conservation of specific orbital energy and specific angular momentum, here:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/676872/123208