# How does Kepler's Second Law show that a planet further from the sun will move slower?

Tags: angular-momentum, orbital-motion, planets, celestial-mechanics

This is probably a very stupid question. We are told that due to Kepler's Second Law, which according to [this very straightforward explanation](https://kids.britannica.com/students/assembly/view/90830):

> "Kepler's second law of planetary motion describes the speed of a
> planet traveling in an elliptical orbit around the Sun. It states that
> a line between the Sun and the planet sweeps equal areas in equal
> times. Thus, the speed of the planet increases as it nears the Sun and
> decreases as it recedes from the Sun."

But it seems to me that a line between the Sun and the planet would always sweep out equal areas, regardless of its distance from the sun or how fast the planet is moving. What am I missing?

Comment: Does this diagram help? https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gist/PM2Ring/8c07b38fdf153f3f6e2a1d3e43890c23/raw/b1238c7da17b3ee26005ddb1b5381ebac26a7dad/KeplerEllipse2.svg

Comment: @PM2Ring Okay thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The heading that you wrote *How does Kepler's Second Law show that the planets further from the sun move slower?* is a question about the whole assembly of planet$\color{red}s$ [plural] orbiting the Sun, whereas Kepler's second law is related to an individual planet.

From the text that you quoted, *Thus, the speed of the **planet** [singular] increases as it nears the Sun and decreases as it recedes from the Sun.*

Here is a pictorial representation of the law.

[image]

Distance 2 > Distance 1 hence Speed 2 > speed 1.

Comment: Okay I just figured it out, but why is it that OTHER planets move slower than others (depending on their distance from the sun)?

Comment: @Gordon That's the topic of Kepler's 3rd law.

Comment: Okay thanks. I just learned about that.

Comment: @Gordon I have Sage/Python code on Github that draws diagrams for Kepler's 2nd law. Click on the `Sage plot demo` link. https://gist.github.com/PM2Ring/8c07b38fdf153f3f6e2a1d3e43890c23?permalink_comment_id=4572815#gistcomment-4572815

Comment: @PM2Ring A nice Sage simulation.

Comment: @PM2Ring This is helpful thanks a lot.

Comment: @Gordon I have some info on planet velocity and Kepler's 3rd law here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/676872/123208

Answer (score 2):

Kepler's Second Law is a precursor to the conservation of angular momentum. In a time $\delta t$, the area swept out by the orbit of a planet is (to first order in $\delta t$) $\frac{1}{2}\left|\mathbf{r}\times\mathbf{v}\delta t\right|=\frac{1}{2}rv\sin(\theta)\delta t$, where $\mathbf{r}$ is the vector pointing from the Sun to the planet, $\mathbf{v}$ is the velocity of the planet, and $\sin(\theta)$ is the angle between $\mathbf{r}$ and $\mathbf{v}$.

So, we see that, when $r$ or $v_\perp$ are increased, the area swept out in a certain time $\delta t$ increases as well. This allows us to conclude that, if the area swept out per unit time is constant, then as $r$ increases, $v_\perp$ must decrease.